# Filtrar resultados en relaciones polimórficas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo un problema al momento de listar los perfiles registrados en mi sistema, básicamente mi problema radica en que al listar los registros de la tabla automáticamente me carga (en este caso) la imagen de perfil y la imagen de portada; para este caso estoy utilizando una relación polimorfismo de uno a muchos asi:

El modelo Perfil

```
public function pictures()
{
  return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Picture', 'picturable');
}
```

El modelo Imagen

```
public function picturable()
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

En el controlador:

```
$profiles = Profile::latest()->paginate(3)->each(function ($profile) {
    $profile->pictures->where('picture_type', 1);
});
```

Lo que sucede es que los perfiles de mis sistema pueden tener un avatar (tipo 1) y portada (tipo 2) y quiero que se muestre el avatar para identificar mas fácil el perfil en la lista; al listar todos los perfiles me trae las dos urls de las imágenes relacionadas con el perfil (avatar y portada), pero si listo solo el perfil si me aplica el filtro.

```
Profile::find(1)->pictures->where('picture_type', 1);
```

Ademas, trato de filtrar solo el link de la imagen pero no logro dar como es el asunto... seria hacer algo asi:

```
Profile::find(1)->pictures->url->where('picture_type', 1)
```

Aun soy muy inexperto con Eloquent y agradezco de corazón su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo de este modo:

```
Profile::with(['pictures' => function($query) {
    $query->wherePictureType(1);
}])->get();
```

O si usas [PHP 7.4 o superior](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arrow.php) puedes tener una sintaxis mas limpia a través de las *arrow functions*:

```
Profile::with(['pictures' => fn($query) => $query->wherePictureType(1)])->get();
```

Dónde:

- Cargamos las relaciones del modelo `Profile`
- Por medio de una función dentro del método `with` construimos un filtro referido a la data que nos devuelve `pictures`

Recomiendo leas [este enlace a detalle](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Gracias, me funciono a la perfección